# How to Bind A model data to all of child Models in Laravel

Tags: laravel, data-binding, model, parent-child

I have a model for custom fields,I want to bind the configuration detail for all model extended by Base model!
my CoctomFormBulder Model

```
class CustomFormBuilder extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = [];

    protected $table = 'custom_fields_configure';
}
```

Here is My base model and what I have try up to now.

```
class BaseModel extends \Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = array('q');

    protected $table        = 'custom_fields_configure';

    protected $appends   = ['configure'];

    public function getConfigerAttribute() {

        if (isset($this->attributes['configure'])) {
        //return URL::asset($this->attributes['image']);
        return $this->attributes['configure'];
        }
    return '';
    }


    public function setConfigerAttribute($configure) {
        $this->attributes['configure'] = $configure;
    }
}
```

How can Bind Data from CustomFormBuilder to all of my models in the app

Answer (score 0):

Just let the models that need that logic extends the 'CustomFormBuilder' class

Comment: In my app Have more than 50 models,making changes may break the app,I just need to push data from Basemodel

Comment: Maybe this is a option: